# Beating $50:50$ chances, limit the risk

Tags: probability, game-theory, martingales

Just wondering. If you flip a coin there are $50:50$ chances you will get the correct side. But if you flip a coin $10,000$ times, you might find yourself in a position, where you would choose the wrong answer for $10$ times in a row.

If you double your bet, that means you lose $x \times n$ money... But is there a way you would limit the risk in a $50:50$ game?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, could you possible rephrase it?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Use [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future posts to properly display mathematical symbols.

Comment: I am just thinking how to beat casino betting on red for an example. Is there anyway to beat it?

Comment: If the probability of winning each even-money bet is $50:50$ or worse, then you cannot raise your expected amount of money above that which you start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability is just a concept of finding how much chance a certain event has. Even if we have a probability of 0.99 of an event occuring, we can't say it will actually happen even if we were to repeat the experiment infinitely.

Unless we have absolute 1 or zero probability, we can't be sure of the outcome. In such a case, getting 10 heads in  consecutive tosses is not a big deal and it is something we can't control (fairly).

**It is important to know that chance is the only thing we can predict before an experiment, not what the outcome would be.**

50-50 chance is the actual representation itself of what we can predict before the experiment. **Unless you can somehow change the odds itself**, ýou can't be sure of occuring of an event in an experiment.